# Find closest k points for every point in row of numpy array without zero value

Tags: python, numpy, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to select k nearest points in numpy 2d array without zero value.

my data is following:

```
print(data)
[[0.   0.   0.   ... 0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   ... 0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   6.41 ... 0.   0.   0.  ]
 ...
 [0.   0.   2.99 ... 0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   ... 0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   ... 0.   0.   0.  ]]
```

I want to find k nearest neighbour among over zero value points.
How can I deal with this problem?

Thank you!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JethroCao I have tried scipy.spatial.KDTree and KNN from sklearn. but I could not find nearest neighbours without zero values..

Comment: @JethroCao Oh! I solved it. when I first apply the location of points, only give points location over zero! Thank you!